# Unable to open captured photo in Android's default image viewer using photo's URI

Tags: android

One of the features of my app is to allow user to assign a photo of an item stored in a DB. This could be done by either taking a new photo with the in-built camera or choosing an image from the library. Then app resizes the captured image, retrieve a full size image URI and store both in a DB. Full size image URI is stored for a later use in case user wants to load a full size image with the default image viewer. Everything works fine except viewer is unable to load image from the captured image URI right after the photo is taken, but it is possible to load the same image only when it is chosen from the library.
Ok here is the code:

manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.packagename.inventoryapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
    </provider>
```

fileprovider.xml

```
    <external-files-path
    name="images"
    path="Pictures" />
```

Handle the camera:

```
  @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
public void onLaunchCamera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    photoFileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
    photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);
    Uri fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            ProductContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileProvider);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

public File getPhotoFileUri(String fileName){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG);
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
    }
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);
}
```

onActivtiyResult (**takenImage** - global Bitmap variable;
**mPicUri** - global Uri variable):

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /* User chose to take a new photo */
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            File takenPhotoUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);
            mPicUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile
                    (this, ProductContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
            Bitmap fullSizeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhotoUri.getAbsolutePath());
            takenImage = BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth
                    (fullSizeImage, mProductImageView.getWidth() / 100 * 50);
        } else { // Result was a failure
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_picture_taken),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /* User chose to take an an existing photo from the gallery */
    else if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPicUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap fullSizeImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap
                        (getContentResolver(), mPicUri);
                takenImage = BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth
                        (fullSizeImage, mProductImageView.getWidth() / 100 * 60);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    mProductImageView.setImageBitmap(takenImage);

    /* Save image and it's URi to the database  */
    if (takenImage != null){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE, DbBitmapUtility.getBytesArray(takenImage));
            values.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_URL, mPicUri.toString());
           int rows = getContentResolver().update(mProductUri, values, null, null);
    }
}
```

Open default image image viewer to load a full size image from Uri:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(mPicUri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

I realise that the problem is in Uri path of a captured photo. When I retrieve it in the above way I get something like:

```
content://com.packagename.inventoryapp.fileprovider/images/InventoryApp/1526632674426.jpg
```

and Image viewer is launching with the blank screen indicating it is searching for the image with no success. 
I tried to get mPicUri with getAbsolutePath() method that leads to the app crashing on launching the intent with that message:

**android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.packagename.inventoryapp/files/Pictures/InventoryApp/1526635391354.jpg }**

On the contrary taking image from the existing library works fine and image Uri looks like:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F2504/ORIGINAL/NONE/1872082740
```

So the question is it possible to somehow retrieve captured image Uri that is not app private and could be red by image viewer?

Comment: `File takenPhotoUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);` It is unclear which/what value you save to your database. Is it `takenPhotoUri.getAbsolutePath()` ? Don't think so as that would nog give you a content scheme. Further you should name a File instance an uri.  It makes your code unreadable.

Comment: check with other device

Comment: I use getAbsolutePath() only to get a Bitmap to store in a DB.  Uri is stored as mPicUri value. Checked this code on an emulator with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.packagename.inventoryapp/files/Pictures/InventoryApp/1526635391354.jpg }
```

That is not a valid `Uri`.

A `Uri` has a scheme. Yours does not. Yours resembles a bare filesystem path. In principle, you could convert that to a `Uri` using `Uri.fromFile()`.
However, on Android 7.0+, using such a `Uri` will fail with a `FileUriExposedException`.

Instead, use the `File` with `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`, and provide that `Uri` to your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. Be sure to also call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on that `Intent`, to allow third-party apps to read the content identified by that `Uri`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do absolutely the same and extract Uri with mPicUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile
                    (this, ProductContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY + ".fileprovider", photoFile); You can see this line in my onActivityResult code. Then pass this Uri to ACTION_VIEW Intent, but viewer cannot read that Uri. Maybe I miss some point?

Comment: As a result FileProvider.getUriForFile() provides this Uri: content://com.packagename.inventoryapp.fileprovider/images/InventoryApp/1526637983295.jpg, but this Uri is unreadable from Image viewer. Or maybe the problem that I do not use addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)?

Comment: @Potato: "Then pass this Uri to ACTION_VIEW Intent, but viewer cannot read that Uri" -- according to that error message, you have modified the `Uri`, such that it only contains a path. For example, somewhere, perhaps you called `Uri.parse()`, supplying just the path. "Or maybe the problem that I do not use addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)?" -- that is an additional problem but will not cause an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Comment: Oh man! You saved my day! The problem was with addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION). Added this line to my Intent and everything is working fine now. Actually there wasn't any mistakes caused by the absence of the FLAG, but Image Viewer just wasn't able to read the provided Uri. It was showing never ending load spinner.